# clock_gettime always shows 0

Tags: c, performance, time

I want to measure a wall clock time with `clock_gettime` but every time I run my code, it shows 0. Why is that? (**I want my result to be in miliseconds.**)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main( int argc, char **argv )
  {
    struct timespec start, stop;
    unsigned long accum;

    if( clock_gettime( CLOCK_REALTIME, &start) == -1 ) {
      perror( "clock gettime" );
      exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    int i;
    for(i=0; i<100000000; i++){int a = 3; int b = 100; int c = a*b;}

    //system( argv[1] );

    if( clock_gettime( CLOCK_REALTIME, &stop) == -1 ) {
      perror( "clock gettime" );
      exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    accum = (unsigned long)( (stop.tv_sec - start.tv_sec) * 1000) + (unsigned long)( (stop.tv_nsec - start.tv_nsec) / 1000000 ) +0.5;
    printf( "%lu\n", accum );
    return( EXIT_SUCCESS );
  }
```

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dead_code_elimination - The compiler is completely removing your loop.

Comment: The way you calculate `accum` you'll see a non-zero value only if the execution takes at least 1 second. And the `for` loop is most likely optimized out. Replace the loop with a `scanf` to increase delay.

Comment: @Mysticial: Ok, thanks!:)) Question about miliseconds: I would like to know if `accum = (unsigned long)( (stop.tv_sec - start.tv_sec) * 1000) + (unsigned long)( (stop.tv_nsec - start.tv_nsec) / 1000000 ) +0.5;
` will give me miliseconds?

Comment: Be careful with `stop.tv_nsec - start.tv_nsec`. It can go negative.

Comment: @Mysticial Interesting!  Why is that?

Comment: @Mysticial: yeah, and how to deal with negative values here?

Comment: Then you "borrow" from the seconds. Same way it works when subtracting numbers by hand.

Comment: @meaning-matters The struct gives you seconds and nanoseconds separately. So it's like two digits of a number. If you subtract `3.1 - 1.9` by digit you will get 2.-8. That `-8` would an example of it doing negative. So you need to carry it over to the next digits. (or in this case, propagate it to the seconds variable)

Comment: @Mysticial Ah of course.  I thought there was something more mystical ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the compiler optimizes away your loop.  Do something inside the loop that can't be simplified easily (by the compiler that is); so create some result.  Then use (e.g. print) this result after the loop.

You could also try to switch off optimisation(s) when you compile.  But since your current loop is very easy to optimise away, this may not make a difference.